# Google Chrome Deprecating Permissions in Cross-Origin Iframes VS Object

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, getusermedia, html-object

Recently Google Chrome made the changes that by default the following permissions cannot be requested or used by content contained in cross-origin iframes:

```
Geolocation (getCurrentPosition and watchPosition)

Midi (requestMIDIAccess)

Encrypted media extensions (requestMediaKeySystemAccess)

Microphone, Camera (getUserMedia)
```

So we have to use the allow attribute with iframe like below:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"></iframe>
```

I want to know how it will effect in case if I use Object tag instead of the iframe?

Thanks in advance.